# regular expression error php error

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have made a regular expression to remove a script tag from a imported page.(used curl)
`<script[\s\S]*?/script>` this is my expresion

when i used it with preg_replace to remove the tag it gave me this error

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'c' in C:\xampp\htdocs\get_page.php on line 21

can anyone help me

thanks

Comment: Clearly that isn't the entire line that you have posted. Please post enough so that we can clearly see what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

You should choose a suitable [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for your regular expression (preferably one that doesn't' occur anywhere in your pattern, so that you don't need to escape). For example:

```
"#<script[\s\S]*?/script>#"
```

Also, don't do that if you are trying to prevent malicious people from injecting Javascript into your page. It can easily be worked around. Use a whitelist of known safe constructs rather than trying to remove dangerous code.

Answer (score 1):

PHP requires delimiters on RegExp patterns. Also, your expression can be simplified.

```
|<script.+/script>|
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
$result = preg_replace('%<script[\s\S]*?/script>%', $change_to, $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap your regexp in forward slashes?

```
$str = preg_replace('/<script[\s\S]*?\/script>/', ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you surround your regular expression with a delimiter, such as `/`? If you didn't, you need to. If you did, and you used `/` (as opposed to your other choices) you'll need to escape the `/` in your `/script`, so it'll look like `\/script` instead.